# Font style translation problem on OSX

Tags: qgis, osx

I have a problem with osx font translate on Qgis.

For example (with a french language selected in osx system preferences) when i want to use a "bold" style, the font stay in "normal".

[image: the font stay in "normal" with french language selected]

On the opposite, with a english language selected in system preferences, everything turn tout normal.

[image]

any ideas to solve my problem ?

Comment: Sounds like this should be a bug report rather than a question on StackExchange.

Comment: Ok I know, bug I can't report any bug on qgis, I tried via ICQ, but for an obscure raison nobody is interested by my story.
Is it possible for you to report it ?

Comment: Issues should be reported by people who can reproduce them. I wouldn't be able to answer any questions that might arise. Issues go here https://issues.qgis.org/projects/qgis/issues/new and not on IRC.

Comment: Ok, they change the rules, thanks you very much, I report the problem right now.